# Why does Tomcat start so much slower with shared libraries?

Tags: java, tomcat

**The problem**

we have a `Tomcat 7.0.35` running with 25 webapps that all share the same libraries with the same versions (it is guaranteed that this will never change!). I figured instead of each project loading the same library, I could just move them to `${catalina.home}/lib` which leads to the desired reduction of memory load.

However this comes at a price: The time for each webapp to be deployed increased from 5 seconds to 2 minutes, which is not viable!

I did some reading (e.g. [Class Loader HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)), unfortunately I was unable to find a way to decrease the startup time. Is there a way to solve this issue?

**Requested profiling information**

I ran `jstack` and `jvisualvm` on the two different scenarios, I will present some findings here (please let me know if you need additional information):

Libraries that are *specific* to each project seem to be loaded with:     `org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResourceInternal`
jstack output for the thread running the method:

```
"localhost-startStop-1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f17f8001800 nid=0x13b8 runnable [0x00007f183c800000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.text.MessageFormat.subformat(MessageFormat.java:1250)
        at java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:819)
        at org.apache.naming.StringManager.getString(StringManager.java:145)
        at org.apache.naming.resources.BaseDirContext.lookup(BaseDirContext.java:500)
        at org.apache.naming.resources.ProxyDirContext.lookup(ProxyDirContext.java:310)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:3011)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResource(WebappClassLoader.java:1262)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoader.java:1499)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2302)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2294)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2308)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2291)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2197)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2154)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2034)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1990)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1976)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1326)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:882)
        - locked <0x00000007f52f3ec0> (a org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:379)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5343)
        - locked <0x00000007f52f3bb8> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        - locked <0x00000007f52f3bb8> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:879)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:636)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1236)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00000007846dfc70> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

Libraries that are *shared* between projects seem to be loaded with:
`at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` which causes the incredible deployment times. JVisualVM displays 98%+ "Self time" for this method during project deployment.
jstack output for the thread running the method:

```
"localhost-startStop-1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f6280001000 nid=0x6ba3 runnable [0x00007f62c4950000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.lang.String.intern(Native Method)
        at java.util.jar.Attributes$Name.<init>(Attributes.java:466)
        at java.util.jar.Attributes.putValue(Attributes.java:168)
        at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:421)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:251)
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:252)
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:239)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:307)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:218)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:345)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:412)
        - locked <0x00000007e8e9d890> (a sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:162)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(URLClassLoader.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoader.java:1528)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2302)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2294)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2308)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.populateJavaClassCache(ContextConfig.java:2294)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2197)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2154)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2034)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1990)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1976)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1326)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:882)
        - locked <0x00000007858db6e0> (a org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:379)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5346)
        - locked <0x00000007858db318> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
        - locked <0x00000007858db318> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:879)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:636)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1236)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x000000078460e618> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

Comment: One option might be to exclude some JAR files from scanning, in each web application. This will prevent tomcat from parsing all of the JARs, and only look through the JARs that are relevant to the task at hand.

Comment: @christopher: But if the situation is like described above, with only the same shared libraries that would have been included in the web apps anyway, that should not make a difference.

Comment: @oschlueter: can you get some stack traces (with jstack for example) during the start up delay to see what is going on?

Comment: Use a profiler and find out what is taking the time.

Comment: It seems to me, you should use here `shared.loader=` property inside `catalina.properties`. This option is omited in mentioned `HOW-TO`, though it still presents in `catalina.properties` of 7th Tomcat version. About it you can read in former documentation for Tomcat 5.5: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Comment: upd: with `shared.loader=` it seems to be more correct to place all common web-apps libraries in separate folder instead of `catalina.home/lib`

Comment: quote from the `Class Loader HOW-TO` page: "Normally, application classes should **NOT** be placed here"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I added the requested profiling information. @mmjmanders The reason for doing this is the massive memory overhead and the fact that we will have to deploy another 20 webapps in the near future.

Answer (score 3):

The WebappClassLoader searches on his own classpath first. So for each class not in the local classpath, all jar files will be looked into. Only then it will look at the delegate to the common classloader.

Say that looking into all of the war's jars takes x amount of time, for the jars its parent classloader it takes y amount of time.

On average loading a class from the correct classloader will take half of the time it takes to scan them everything.

Loading a class from the WebappClassLoader will take x/2 time.

Loading a class from the parent classloader will take x + y/2.

Depending on x and y you could change the order in which the classloaders are used.
If y is larger than x, you should keep thee default setup, if x is larger than you can try to reverse the lookup order. If you do so loading a class from the common classloader will take y/2 time but a class from the WebappClassLoader will take y + x/2.

The WebbappClassLoader has a delegate property for this setting it to true should do the trick.
See [Common Attributes](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/loader.html#Common_Attributes)

Answer (score 0):

In short: add value for `shared.loader` in `conf/catalina.properties`

```
shared.loader=shared/*.jar
```

In more words:

```
# List of comma-separated paths defining the contents of the "shared"
# classloader. Prefixes should be used to define what is the repository type.
# Path may be relative to the CATALINA_BASE path or absolute. If left as blank,
# the "common" loader will be used as Catalina's "shared" loader.
# Examples:
#     "foo": Add this folder as a class repository
#     "foo/*.jar": Add all the JARs of the specified folder as class
#                  repositories
#     "foo/bar.jar": Add bar.jar as a class repository
# Please note that for single jars, e.g. bar.jar, you need the URL form
# starting with file:.
shared.loader=shared/*.jar
```

Tomcat 6+ by default has hierarchy http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

```
  Bootstrap
      |
   System
      |
   Common
   /     \
Webapp1   Webapp2 ...
```

compare with default in 5.5 http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html

```
 Bootstrap
      |
   System
      |
   Common
  /      \
Catalina Shared
         /   \
    Webapp1  Webapp2 ...
```

So by enabling shared location, that will contain only your jars, and separately from Tomcat lib folder, that has 21 jars already, you may get at least cleaner view of jars.